# Ember.js Data. What .js files(libraries) to include?

Tags: ember.js

I really want to try ember-data with ember.js. Looking at the ember-data project here, https://github.com/emberjs/data/tree/master/packages/ember-data/lib 
I a not very sure all the .js files that I need to pick.
I believe main.js is ember.js itself. Not sure of the rest?

If you know any samples that use ember-data please point me there as well.

Edit 1:
I am looking to pull the edge version.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to use the edge version, you have to pull down the whole git repo, cd into it, and run the rake task to compile them. if you do a rake -t it will give you the exact task name.

Comment: Thank you :) "bundle exec rake dist" is the one :)

Comment: Builds, both beta releases and edge (canary), can be found at http://emberjs.com/builds

Comment: Seconding What Mr. Wagenet said - this answer is now out of date.

Answer (score 4):

if you just want a single js file, you can simple click on downloads on the right side. there you'll find two alredy joined files. The normal, commented an a minified version.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that:) I was more looking to pull the edge ones and wasnt very sure all the files that were needed. Is there any commands that builds ember-data.js out of edge?

Answer (score 2):

You should use a built version of Ember Data. These can now be found at http://emberjs.com/builds.